# NSInvocationOperation question

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a method in my Cocoa Mac application that goes through all subscribed feeds in my application's PubSub Client and marks all the entries as read.

The logic looks something like this...

```
NSArray *feeds = [[PSClient applicationClient]feeds];

for(PSFeed *feed in feeds)
{
    for(PSEntry *entry in [feed entries])
    {
        entry.read = NO;
    }
}
```

If there are a large number of unread feeds it can take a while to cycle through them all (relatively speaking). I would like the user to be able to do other things like scroll through articles while the other stuff is going on in the background. So I have an NSInvocationOperation setup to call the method, like so...

```
NSInvocationOperation *opr = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(markAllReadOperation) object:nil];
[que addOperation:opr];
[opr release];
```

The application still experiences severe slowdowns while the loop is running. And the UI is nearly unresponsive. Am I missing something with NSInvocationOperation, or is my logic just inherently slow?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for...Grand Central Dispatch!

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [obj enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [obj setRead:NO];
        }];
    }];
});
```

Of course, Grand Central Dispatch (and blocks) were both introduced in Mac OS X 10.6, so that may not be usable if you need to support older versions of OS X.

Comment: I have no problem with backwards support, I plan on taking this to Mac App Store... So users will have 10.6 by default. Now what will this improve upon that NSInvocationOpeartion fails to do? I was under the impression that NSOperation provided the same functionality just at a higher and less involved layer. UPDATE: I tried this but I'm still get a similar lack of UI response while the operation is running on the separate thread.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense...I'd also recommend profiling in Instruments to see what call is causing the block.

Comment: I haven't used profiling in instruments before, what exactly would I be looking for. From what I can tell, it seems PubSub is taking up the highest percentage while the event is occurring. While exploring the symbol names my method is occurring on "_dispatch_worker_thread2" while the actual PubSub operations like "sendChangesSinceDate" (which is taking up the highest percentage while my operation is working) is occuring on the "Thread 0x5565 : Main Thread".

Comment: This suggests that at least some functionality within the PubSub framework is coded to use the main thread. If that's the case, there's not much that you can do, besides writing your own code to handle these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If your UI is unresponsive, then it sounds like something is running on the main thread. You're not using the `mainQueue` are you?

I think your best bet would be to use Instruments to see exactly what code is causing the slowdown using the Time Profiler instrument.

Comment: I'm not using the mainQueue, I'm creating a new NSOperationQueue object. The UI is somewhat responsive but it has considerable lag. The only thing I have going on in the main thread is the basic UI interaction which is lagging.